# How to create file in python?

Tags: file

Anyone know how to use python for creation file?
when i write
text_file= open("productlist.txt", "w")
I need create file before star use pragram, maybe python can do it independently ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is not really clear, try to edit it a little to make it better.

In general, you don't need to create the file before you start your program, the 'w' option will write to that file, and will create the file if it doesn't exist.

Now, if you just want to create an empty file, use the 'x' option, as follows:

```
f = open("yourfile.txt", "x")
```

You can create all the files that you want with this, even without closing the handle.